# Why the Suffix Array use less space than the Suffix Tree?

Tags: data-structures, suffix-tree, suffix-array

I'm researching about Suffix Array and Suffix Tree for my project. 
In several papers such as :

1. "Suffix arrays: A new method for on-line string searches" by Manber and Myers - 1993.
2. "Simple Linear Work Suffix Array Construction" by Juha Karkkainen and Peter Sanders - 2003.

The author said that: **"The advantage of the Suffix Array use less space than the Suffix Tree"**.

My question is "How can we know that ? Do we have any mathematical proof for that or we base on the practical experiments ?"

By observation, an array data structure seems to use less space than a tree data structure. But I want to know exactly why.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the paper mentioned at below link (section 1.2.4) will give answer to your query:

http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs548/suffix.pdf